# SML: List Greater than X

Tags: sml, smlnj

New to SML and looking for a little assistance with a list question. 
Basically I need to create a list that is greater than variable X.

Example:

```
test(5,[13,2,4,17,8]) 

Expected Result: (13,17,8)
```

I know that I can either do this by writing two separate functions, one that determines the value is less than x and then runs through the list. Or I can try to and do it all in one function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter` to filter out elements of `[13,2,4,17,8]` that are greater than `5`.

```
> List.filter (fn x => x > 5) [13,2,4,17,8];
val it = [13, 17, 8] : int LIST.list
```